# Contacts synced when a Google account is added, how to remove them after removing the account?

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account, realme

I have a Realme phone. I added a Google email to the phone, and the contact numbers saved with that email got synced with the phone. Now I removed that email, but the contacts from that account are still there on the phone.

How can I remove them?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Looks like there's a Q&A for the same problem: [Deleting unwanted contacts after accidental account sync](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/144066/44325). Consider reading and trying the answers there and let us know the result. Thanks.